# What is this delphi (default?) font?

Tags: delphi, fonts

I would like to use exactely this font:

[image]

[image]

It is from a Delphi application, and I guess the programmer's didn't change the default font, but that is just a guess.

What is this font name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first thought it was either Tahoma or Segoe UI.

Tahoma is the default VCL (Delphi) font, and it was the standard Windows UI font prior to Windows Vista. These days, the [standard Windows GUI font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-fonts) is Segoe UI.

But after carefully trying various fonts and sizes, I am positive that this is Arial. With Arial, I obtain a pixel-perfect match, even with Clear Type antialiasing.

That's an uncommon choice for a GUI font. I recommend against it.

(Clearly, the programmer did change the font from the default one.)